# Position:absolute / fixed changes display-property to block

Tags: css

Today I faced an interesting problem at work.
When I style an inline-element with position:absolute or fixed it behaves like a block-element which can have a height and with.
Here a short example:

```css
span {
  background: red;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
}

span#absolute {
  position: absolute;
  top:30px;
  left:30px;
}
```

```html
<span>Inline</span>

<span id="absolute">Inline, too</span>
```

As you can see both spans have `height` and `width` (which should be ignored on inline-elemens). However it gets applied when using `posision:absolute`.

So my question: Is the second `span` behaving like `display:block` completely or is it just a semi-block-behaviour?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html#dis-pos-flo:

> The three properties that affect box generation and layout — 'display', 'position', and 'float' — interact as follows:
>   2. […] if 'position' has the value 'absolute' or 'fixed', the box is absolutely positioned, the computed value of 'float' is 'none', and display is set according to the table below.

And in that mentioned *table below*, you see that for the *specified value* `inline` (which `span` has by default from the user agent stylesheet), the *computed value* is … `block`

Answer (score 1):

Per Chrome's computed styles on span#absolute, the element has a display:block property.[image]

Comment: I'am curious if this is covered somewhere in the specs